# How can I change the colormap of a contour plot in R

Tags: r, heatmap, contour, color-scheme, colormap

I am trying to change the color of a contour plot. I'm trying to use geom_contour_filled() to get the green to yellow color, but it's not working. Could anyone help me on this. The below program is working but I don't get it work when I'm trying to change the colormap.

```
ggplot(contour_Test, aes(V1, V2) ) +
stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon", colour="white", bins = 6) +
xlab("Time (sec)") + ylab("FRET Efficiency") + theme_classic() + ylim(-0.1, 1) + geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype="dotted", color = "black", size=1) +
ggtitle("Plot")
```

Comment: Does `scale_fill_gradient()` or `scale_fill_manual()` do what you want?

Comment: You're much more likely to get answers if you provide a minimal, reproducible example that contains the data and code necessary to replicate the problem you're having.